# A single case of Safari on iOS9 not connecting to websocket

Tags: ios, iphone, asp.net-mvc, safari, websocket

I have an issue with a single (at least for now) iPhone not being able to connect to websockets. Unfortunately I don't have access to the device and I can't run more tests on it at the moment, so no proper network dumps or anything else deeper level debugging available. Can't test on other network connections either at the moment.

Everything works perfectly with Chrome 45, Firefox 40, Chrome 45 on Android (many devices), Safari on iOS9 (device A), Safari on iOS8 (device B) etc. No errors, no cutoffs, nothing. Just works.

My websocket server runs on IIS 8.5 / ASP.NET, created as an API controller with the typical way (PullHandler is an async Task `while`ing until connection closes)

```
if (HttpContext.Current.IsWebSocketRequest)
{
    HttpContext.Current.AcceptWebSocketRequest(PullHandler);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.SwitchingProtocols);
}
else
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Bad request");
```

This should not cause any issues, especially this one. The client side JavaScript is also the simple

```
new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "/api/Some/Endpoint);
```

I am using plain HTTP, no SSL/TLS.

When trying on iPhone device X with iOS9 (13A344, not entirely sure of which model) it just can't get the connection. I am also using SignalR which automatically goes into *longPolling* transport on this device. With others it's nicely on *webSockets* transport.

Quick testing on UK Orange 3G connection showed on my HTTP logs that for some reason the request for my endpoint has gone to the else branch, like something had stripped the upgrade headers away.

> GET /api/Some/Endpoint 80 - Mozilla/5.0+(iPhone;+CPU+iPhone+OS+9_0+like+Mac+OS+X)+AppleWebKit/601.1.46+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Version/9.0+Mobile/13A344+Safari/601.1 - 400

Status 400 is clearly showing the bad request that my code is sending if the request is not a proper websocket request. I don't know if there could be some transparent proxy, that could explain this. The 400 response was received without any delays.

But this was a problem also through wifi on the same device. Again, a laptop with OS X and Safari had no issues on the same wifi to connect to SignalR and my websocket server. Only the iPhone had issues. On wifi I didn't get any attempts to connect on the logs and SignalR also immediately went into longPolling transport. The wifi apparently used Virgin Media's network based on IP address.

On wifi there is first an open event. Then after some time there is a close event with status 1006, which is abnormal termination without a close packet. My code tries to connect again and the same happens. Strangely there is no log entry at the web server, but it might just be Safari's way to post the open event even though an actual connection was not established and after a timeout it sends the close event.

The device should not have any proxies set up and other browsing works without issues. Unfortunately I couldn't get any information about any other site that would use websockets working or not on that device.

Has anyone run into this kind of situation? I do understand that the 3G might just be a misbehaving proxy, but the wifi issue cannot be explained with that.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Facing same issue...

Comment: @Programmer The issue was most likely on the operator network. Using SSL websockets bypasses them and works.

Comment: We have TLS1.2 in the server still it is not working.. can you please explain how did it work..

Answer (score 0):

Just want to expand the universe for this issue.

I Have an app that runs great in simulator.  App has both http Jason IO and web socket IO.

Now that I can target my iPhone and not the simulator.  App on iPhone successfully does the http Json stuff but not the web socket stuff.

While I am not using safari and js my symptoms are very similar to yours.  I am using Xcode 7 to generate code that targets to iPhone 5 using iOS 9.0.

Comment: I have the same problem